# Laravel pass parameters to route/action

Tags: laravel

If I want to construct this url: /categories/5/update/?hidden=1 how could I pass both {id} param and hidden param (as GET) ?

My route is:

```
Route::get('categories/{id}/update', 'CategoryController@update');
```

I don't want to make a form and put it as POST because I have a number of buttons which simply hides/shows/removes a category and dont want to make a lot of forms for simple actions, although it has nothing to do with the question

I'm just a little bit confused, because it seems like `action('CategoryController@update', [$id, 'hidden' => 1])` constructs the right URL but I got no idea how it's distinguished that the first one ($id) must be in URL and the second is a GET param

Comment: Your `action()` call constructs the correct URL because it'll use the first unnamed value as the value of the first parameter, then attach any others as GET parameters.

Comment: So it's okay to use it that way?

Comment: Yeah, if it works it works :) The other answer is an option too, which would result in the same thing.

Answer (score 2):

You may also try this to generate the `URL`:

```
$action = action('CategoryController@update', [id => $id]) . '?hidden=1';
```

Also, `query string` could be passed with any route even without mentioning about that in Route declaration.